# GNU Screen: run arbitrary command in the status bar?

Tags: gnu-screen

Is it possible to get GNU Screen to display the output of an arbitrary command, *e.g.* `who | wc -l`, in the status bar, refreshing it, say, every minute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can using the backtick feature.
[Backtick](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Backtick.html%E2%80%8E)

You put a line in your screenrc file:

```
backtick 1 0 5 /bin/date
```

If I understand correctly, it means backtick id 1, which runs command `/bin/date`, produces output valid for 0 seconds and the caption/hardstatus should be updated every 5 seconds.

Now, you can use the string `` %1` `` inside your hardstatus for substitution, eg

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "date output: %1`"
```

In your case, I think you'll have to write a script. For example, `$HOME/my_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
who | wc -l
```

In your `~/.screenrc`:

```
backtick 1 0 60 $HOME/my_script.sh
hardstatus alwayslastline "who|wc -l output: %1`"
```

Obviously you won't want exactly that, but just add `` %1` `` to whatever else you have. Note that your script output can't include string escapes for screen to expand, e.g. if your script is `echo "%{bg}blue on green%{dd}"` it won't be coloured, you'll just see `${bg}` and `${dd}` in your status line.